# MVC.Net Description of user

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-membership

Using C# how do I retrieve a users description and email?

I used plain ASP.Net Membership to set up the user-accounts.

Comment: are you using ASP.Net Membership?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could retrieve the authenticated username by using the [`User`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.user.aspx) property inside your controller action and then query the memebership provider to retrieve additional user info which is stored in the database:

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Foo()
{
    // fetch the connected user from the authentication cookie
    string username = User.Identity.Name; 
    // query the datastore to retrieve additional user information
    var userInfo = Membership.Provider.GetUser(username, false);
    string email = userInfo.Email;
    string comment = userInfo.Comment;
    return View();
}
```